# complex LINQ multiple tables with many to many

Tags: c#, linq

I am still new to LINQ. 
Is this scenario possible to do with linq?

I have 4 tables:

```
1. Garage (ID, Name)
2. Car (ID, GarageID, Name) -- a garage has multiple cars.
3. Dealer (ID, Name)
4. Car_Dealership (ID, CarID, DealerID) -- many to many table between car and dealer
```

I want to get a collection of all garages along with every dealer that each garage dealt with.

How can you do this with LINQ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is certainly possible.  Are you encountering any issues or do you just want to check if it is possible?

Comment: like I said I am a beginner, so I don't know how to do it. I've gone through many examples, but none is similar to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
var map =
  from garage in Garages
  join car in Cars on garage.ID equals car.GarageID
  join car_dealership in Car_Dealerships on car.ID equals car_dealership.CarID
  join dealer in Dealers on car_dealership.DealerID equals dealer.ID
  group dealer by garage;

foreach (var garage in map)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Garage: " + garage.Key.Name);

  foreach (var dealer in garage)
    Console.WriteLine("  Dealer: " + dealer.Name);
}
```

In the future, please post what you've tried so that we can help you with the specific problems you're running into.

Comment: `In the future, please post what you've tried so that we can help you with the specific problems you're running into.` Why? There are always some *Andrew* s to answer such questions :)

Comment: You're awesome Andrew. It worked like a charm! Your example, unlike the ones I researched, shows me that linq is alot like sql queries and since I know how to do tsql, I would have a good starting point to have my next question attached to some trial first.